# How to negotiate HTTP request authentication by sending OS session data in python on linux?

Tags: python, http, python-requests, kerberos

### Requirement:

Send a HTTP request via python requests library by using OS authentication (without manually providing user/pwd). I can do that in Python on Windows using "from requests_negotiate_sspi import HttpNegotiateAuth" library, as I logged in as Active Directory account, whereas in Linux platform since it is local user (not AD user) I am unable to do the same.

I tried with "requests-kerberos" library in linux, but end up with access denied error. So, could anyone help me on this?

Expected outcome:

```py
from requests_kerberos import HTTPKerberosAuth
r = requests.get(URL, auth=HTTPKerberosAuth(), verify=False)

r.status_code = 200
r.json() = {'Content':'<DATA>'}
```

Actual outcome:

```
r.status_code = 401
r.json() =

<h2>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</h2>
<h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
```

Comment: Do you have a valid kerberos ticket?

Comment: To be very clear: You don't need to use Kerberos to log into your OS account to get a Kerberos ticket. (You _do_ need the relevant tooling installed and configured, but that's system administration rather than software development and so not on-topic here).

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano - Yes, I do have

Comment: @gjvignesh: What do you have in `klist` before running your script?

Comment: @user1686: I am mentioning here without actual data, due to privacy policy. This is the output i get from klist.

Ticket cache: KEYRING:persistent:0:0
Default principal: <USER DATA>
Valid starting       Expires              Service principal        renew until

Comment: That's perfectly useless... In that case: 1) Does `kvno HTTP/your.webapp.domain` succeed (i.e. do you get a version number, not an error message)? 2) Set `rdns = false` in [libdefaults] in /etc/krb5.conf. Does the same `kvno` command succeed?

Comment: @user1686 - I get below kvno for the service principal

kvno = 7.

Note: rdns is already set false in /etc/krb5.conf